# How to handle redirects in Wallaby?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, wallaby

I have a feature test written like this:

```
confirmation_page = visit(session, "/confirm/#{id}")
confirmation_page
    |> click(link("Decline"))
confirmation_page
    |> assert_text("You have declined.")
```

However the test always fails, because in controller, on click of this page, I am doing this:

```
 conn
    |> put_flash(:info, "You have declined.")
    |> redirect(to: Routes.group_path(conn, :show, group.slug))
```

So the flash is coming on the redirected page, and not the original page. How can I wait for the redirect and assert on the new page?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can simply provide a sleep timer like `:time.sleep(1000)` before asserting over element.
2. You can retry like waiting for page to be refreshed. You can use [`Wallaby.retry/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/wallaby/Wallaby.Browser.html#retry/2) to retry until window is refreshed on specific url. We can get current url of window using [`Wallaby.current_url/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/wallaby/Wallaby.Browser.html#retry/2). Code would look something like this.

```
1 retry = fn -> if Wallaby.current_url == "expected" do                                                                                                      
2     ┆   ┆   ┆   assert_text(confirmation_page)                                                                                                              
3     ┆   ┆   ┆ else                                                                                                                                          
4     ┆   ┆   ┆   {:error, :url_not_refreshed}                                                                                                                
5     ┆   ┆   ┆end                                                                                                                                            
6     ┆   end                                                                                                                                                 
7                                                                                                                                                             
8 assert {:ok, response} = Wallaby.retry(retry, 5000) ## default timeout option after which it
```

Comment: It didn't work. The weird part is that same test is succeeding in someone else's machine with same `chrome` and `chromedriver` version.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use
`assert_has(session, css("element ID or class", text: "You have declined."))`

The assert has have build in retry so it will wait for this element to show up so I think it will solve your problem.